# Is there a shorter/better way to validate request params?

Tags: python, validation, python-2.7, flask, werkzeug

I keep repeating blocks like this to validate request params. Is there a shorter/better way to implement this?

```
count = request.args.get('count', DEFAULT_COUNT)
if count:
    try:
        count = int(count)
    except ValueError:
        count = DEFAULT_COUNT
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. The [`args`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.args) attribute of a Flask/Werkzeug `Request` object is an `ImmutableMultiDict`, which is a subclass of `MultiDict`. The [`MultiDict.get()`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get) method accepts a `type` argument which does exactly what you want:

```
count = request.args.get('count', DEFAULT_COUNT, type=int)
```

Here's the relevant section of the docs:

> **`get(key, default=None, type=None)`**
>
> Return the default value if the requested data doesn’t exist. If `type` is provided and is a callable it should convert the value, return
>   it or raise a `ValueError` if that is not possible. In this case the
>   function will return the default as if the value was not found:
>
> ```
> >>> d = TypeConversionDict(foo='42', bar='blub')
> >>> d.get('foo', type=int)
> 42
> >>> d.get('bar', -1, type=int)
> -1
> ```